# Search for value from one array in another array and modify array if not found - numpy

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have an array of `a` of shape `(N,k)` and another array `b` of shape `(N,)`. I want to check if the *ith* value in `b` is contained in `a[i]`. If it is not present, I want to replace `a[i,k]` with `b[i]`. An example:

```
a = np.array([[1,  2, 2, 3,  4, 5],
              [1,  2, 3, 3,  4, 5],
              [1,  2, 3, 4,  4, 5],
              [1,  2, 3, 4,  5, 5],
              [1,  2, 3, 4,  5, 6]])

b = np.array([1,7,3,8,9])
```

The output array should look like this:

```
np.array([[1,  2, 2, 3,  4, 5],
          [1,  2, 3, 3,  4, 7],
          [1,  2, 3, 4,  4, 5],
          [1,  2, 3, 4,  5, 8],
          [1,  2, 3, 4,  5, 9]])
```

Writing loops over `N` seems to be very inefficient. In my dataset typically `N` is of the order of 10 million while `k` is about 50 to 100. Is there an efficient way to vectorize this using `numpy` functions?

Comment: Have you tried the straightforward brute force approach? How long does it take?

Comment: you have no choice, you must loop over N any way

Comment: Coming from a `C++` background my first stab at a problem is loops but I have always found that there are more "Pythonic" ways to achieve what I want... Brute force takes about 10 to 15 minutes on my data. I was hoping that the internal numpy code can handle looping over `N`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices where to replace can be found doing:

```
s = a - b[:, None]
TOL = 1.e-6
ind = np.where(~(np.abs(s) <= TOL).any(axis=1))[0]
```

and thanks to NumPy's fancy indexing you can update your array in-place without for loops:

```
a[ind, :] = b[ind][:, None]
```

Comment: Nice logic. Works like a charm! Although, for my specific case the final replace statement should be `a[ind, a.shape[0]] = b[ind]` as I want to replace only the last element.

Comment: It seems like we are comparing the difference to a very small value `TOL`. Is 1.e-6 some form of limit in Python or is this something arbitrary and in this case the match will be precise upto 6 decimal points?

Comment: @RazorXsr if you are dealing with integers `np.where(~(s == 0))` just fine. Using tolerances makes it more general.

Comment: @RazorXsr from your first comment... perhaps you want `a[ind, ind:] = b[ind][:, None]`